# How to read information of QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qstring, qlineedit, qspinbox

I have a `QtableWidget` and I have stored a `QSpinBox` in.
as below:
(`product` is a class).

```
void MainWindow:: add_to_basket (product p){

    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(0);

    QLineEdit *qle=new QLineEdit();
    qle->setText(p.get_name());
    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0,0,qle);

    QLineEdit *qle1=new QLineEdit();
    qle1->setText(QString::number(p.get_price()));
    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0,1,qle1);

    QSpinBox *qsb=new QSpinBox();
    qsb->setValue(p.get_count());
    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0,2,qsb);
}
```

now I want to access data stored in `QSpinBox` but don't know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, inserting to row 0 of the QTableWidget every time will likely be a problem, you may want to check that as well.

Answering your question now, to get the value from the spinbox, simply use
`qsb->value()`

See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html